# Rockets are not changing direction after mutation

Tags: javascript, machine-learning

I have a problem with some machine learning stuff. After the first gen rockets are not mutating and just follow the same path. I tried different ways to solve that as you can see but neither of them work. I wrote this in openprocessing.org but also tried to do that on local. I don`t see problem buti think it is in the Rocket constructor function.

```js
var rockets = [];
var bf = -1;
var br;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(100);
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 50);
  frameRate(10);
  target = createVector(width, height / 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rockets.push(new Rocket());
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 40, 40);
  ellipse(width - 10, height / 2, 40, 40);
  for (i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++) {
    rockets[i].show();
    //console.log(rockets[i].pos.y);
    if (!rockets[i].killed) {
      rockets[i].applyForce(); //it is a fittness counter inside
    }
  }
  //console.log(rockets);
  if (rockets[0].counter >= rockets[0].route.length) {
    findBest();
    respawn();
  }
}

function respawn() {
  var news = mutate(br);
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rockets.push(new Rocket());
    //console.log(rockets);
    rockets[i].route = news[i];
  }
}

function findBest() {
  for (var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++) {
    //console.log(rockets[i].fittness);
    if (rockets[i].fittness > bf) {
      br = rockets[i].route;
      bf = rockets[i].fittness;
    }
  }
  rockets = [];
}

function mutate(arr) {
  var news = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var tempArr = arr;
    tempArr[floor(random(arr.lenth))] = p5.Vector.random2D().setMag(30);
    news.push(tempArr);
  }
  return news;
}

function Rocket(a) {
  this.pos = createVector(width / 2, height / 2);
  this.route = [];
  this.counter = 0;
  this.fittness = 0;
  this.killed = false;
  //console.log(a);
  if (!a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      this.route.push(p5.Vector.random2D());
      this.route[i].setMag(20);
      //console.log("!A");
      // console.log(i);
    }
  } else {
    // this is not used 
    this.route = a;
    // for(var i = floor(random(a.length-1)); i<a.length; i++) {
    //console.log(this.route[i]);
    b = floor(random(this.route.length - 1));
    console.log("before: ", this.route[b]);
    this.route[b] = p5.Vector.random2D().setMag(30); 
    //this.route[i].rotate(0.2*pow(-1, i));
    console.log("after: ", this.route[b]);
    //}
  }

  //console.log(mutate(this.route));
  this.applyForce = function() {
    if (this.counter == this.route.length - 1) {
      this.countFittness();
      //console.log(this.fittness);
      this.killed = true;
    }
    this.pos.add(this.route[this.counter]);
    this.counter++;
  }
  this.countFittness = function() {

    this.fittness = 1 / this.pos.dist(target) * 100;
    //console.log(this.fittness);
  }
  this.show = function() {
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 10, 10);

  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.12/p5.js"></script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: You are never setting the parameter in rocket? so surely you need to do `new Rocket(True/False);` to make that if statement do the else

Comment: @Deckerz, thank you but I tried to do that and now im just creating new rockets and only than giving them non-random/best mutated route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice code. It seems there is an error in your mutate function:

```
function mutate(arr) {
  var news = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var tempArr = arr;
    tempArr[floor(random(arr.length))] = p5.Vector.random2D().setMag(30);
    news.push(tempArr);
  }
  return news;
}
```

When you use

```
var tempArr = arr;
```

in javascript you do not get a copy of the array. Both arrays will point to the same reference. When you mutate one the original also mutates. That way eventually all of the routes for the rockets will turn out to be the same.

Try ...

```
var tempArr = arr.slice();
```

The slice() operation clones the array and returns a reference to the new array.

There is also a small typo in the same function. I think it should be ...

```
tempArr[floor(random(arr.length))] = p5.Vector.random2D().setMag(30);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I was stuck on this more time than i did the whole project xd

Comment: It's a nice project! I really liked investigating it.